# How to merge column this specific way in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My original table is this; 
TableName= NewRetail

```
CustomerID  1    2   3      4    5     6      7.....30
    1       30  31   Null  Null Null   Null   Null
    2       24  78    35   72   Null   Null   Null
```

I want to store this table in 'Retail'

`CustomerId  Itemset
   1            30
   1            31
   2            24
   2            78
   2            35
   2            72`

There are no duplicates in any row in Original(Source) Table.

Thanks. I tried using Loops but couldn't make it work. Been stuck at it since three days.

Comment: Are you using MySQL and/or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: `Mysql <> Sql server`. Choose one

Comment: You tagged your question with MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server. SO for which one is it supposed to work? For Microsoft SQL Server you could use [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, im using sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerId, [1] AS ItemSet FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, [2] FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, [3] FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, [4] FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, [5] FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, [6] FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, [7] FROM NewRetail UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT CustomerId, [30] FROM NewRetail
)t
WHERE ItemSet IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CustomerId
```

---

Using dynamic SQL:

```
;WITH Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP 30 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT @sql = @sql +  
    CASE 
        WHEN @sql = '' THEN 'SELECT CustomerId, [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), N) + '] AS ItemSet FROM NewRetail' 
        ELSE ' UNION ALL' + CHAR(10) +' SELECT CustomerId, [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), N) + '] FROM NewRetail'
    END
    FROM Tally

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT *
FROM (
    ' + @sql + CHAR(10) +
')t
WHERE ItemSet IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CustomerId'

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Nicely done, but would there be any advantage to this solution over using `PIVOT`s?

Comment: I find it more readable. As for performance, I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean this solution works but there are much much more easiest and efficient ways.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But we do not know if the OP has the ability to use `CROSS APPLY` or even know how to use it.

Comment: @wewesthemenance Can you please help me with one more query.  If I want to find out all CustomerID that have 30 and 31 as Itemset for the very same table mentioned above. I tried using & Operator but the result is not correct

Comment: @Api: Replace `ItemSet IS NOT NULL` with `ItemSet IN (30, 31)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `table valued constructor` with `Cross apply` to `unpivot` the data

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       Itemset
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES ([1]),([2]),([3]),([4]),([5]),([6]),([7]),...) cs (Itemset)
WHERE  Itemset IS NOT NULL
```

**Dynamic Version**

```
DECLARE @itemset VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql     NVARCHAR(max);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT TOP 30 Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
         FROM   sys.columns)
SELECT @itemset += '(' + Quotename(RN) + '),'
FROM   cte

SET @itemset = LEFT(@itemset, Len(@itemset) - 1)
SET @sql = 'SELECT CustomerID,
           Itemset
    FROM   Yourtable
           CROSS apply (VALUES ' + @itemset
           + ') cs (Itemset)
    WHERE  Itemset IS NOT NULL '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple `UNPIVOT` operation. NULLs automatically eliminated from result:

```
declare @t table(custid int, [1] int, [2] int, [3] int)

insert into @t values
(1, 10, 30, null),
(2, 30, 40, 50)


select custid, c from @t
unpivot(c for p in([1], [2], [3])) p
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1733

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.